# Onepage checkout: Submit order button not working

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, onepage-checkout

I am working on a Magento store V. 1.8.1.0 that does the following error:

On onepage checkout.

1. Customer clicks on "Place order"
2. The button becomes disabled, shows a spinner (all goood so far).
3. Button goes back to normal. Nothing further happens.

[image]

The order gets created in the backend AND the customer's Credit Card gets charged. If the customer clicks again, another order gets created and his/her card gets charged again.

Does someone know why this happens?

According to the store owner, the store worked fine until a week ago when this error started to appear.

Comment: Check Magento logs and also check also what should happen in the case of successful order placement, should it be redirect to success page then where it is getting stuck. Do some debugging http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: It means getDescription() method is being called on the incorrect object. Rectify this calling.

Answer (score 3):

First find the Bug this way:

Go to the checkout page & open the console (you need firebug if mozila firefox). 
You should be able to see one ajax call on click place order. See the ajax response. Here you can find the error.

Now try below possible solutions:

- Probably error comes in `onepagecontroller.php` `saveAction`. Now just look in that file.
- If you installed any third party extension for checkout try to disable it.
- Clear the caches in backend in System->Cache Management.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Stripe Payment method:**
Open the page in Mozilla firefox and check in firebug. if its giving invalid stripe publishable key error, on clicking Place order button, then add the following scripts to your footer.php

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
   Stripe.setPublishKey('Your Stripe Publishable Key');
</script>
```

This will work for you.